# Datasource verification problems after Windows updates

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

Yesterday windows updates were installed on my laptop, and afterwards many features of ColdFusion were out of configuration.

I am using ColdFusion 2016  and SQL Server 2016 RC.

I fixed a number of issues (see below) but still get the message

> `Connection verification failed for data source: MT_EL
>   java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [Macromedia][SQLServer
>   JDBC Driver]Error establishing socket to host and port: 8500:1433.
>   Reason: Network is unreachable: connect The root cause was that:
>   java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [Macromedia][SQLServer
>   JDBC Driver]Error establishing socket to host and port: 8500:1433.
>   Reason: Network is unreachable: connect.`

The DSNs had been verifying for at least a year before the problems occurred.

So far I have done the following:

1. Both SQL Server and CF Server had to be started again. SQL Server was not a problem but the CF Server would not start. I went to the `jvm.config` file and reduced the `-xms` setting. This did not solve anything, so I looked at the logs. From the logs it was apparent that the `neo-security.xml` file was corrupted, and upon checking I saw that neo-security.xml was now empty. `neo-datasource`, `neo-drivers` and one or two other files were also empty. The back-ups of these files were also empty, but I found some old versions in another place, and copied them over. Now I was able to start the CF Server and get into the CF Administrator, but had to set up user names/passwords and also DSNs again.
2. SQL Server Configuration Manager had been moved to a different folder, but I found it and soon saw an error message saying that SQL Server Configuration Manager could not connect to the wmi provider. I fixed this by opening a command prompt in administrator mode and typing`mofcomp "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\13\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"`.
3. Now I could get into SQL Server Configuration Manager, but for some reason it is listed twice, The malfunctioning one still says I cannot connect to the wmi provider, but expanding the functioning one, I found that TCP/IP is enabled and the default port is 1433.
4. I checked the firewall and could not see any issues there.
5. SQL permissions + log in/password credentials are the same as before, when there were no DSN verification problems.
6. I have tried ports 8501 and 8502, but the above error persists.
7. I have checked the SQL Server logs. It is apparent that a number of errors occurred yesterday and certain features were disabled. However it is evident that these issues have now been resolved, and the most recent messages are of informational type  and state that no user action is necessary.

Anyone any ideas?  Thank you in advance for any comments/assistance.

Comment: 1. Try temporarily disabling the firewall 2. Can you telnet into port 1433 on the SQL Server? 3. Check whether SQL Server authentication is enabled.

Comment: Can you connect to SQL Server with Management Studio similar tool? Also, you ran Windows Update and it messed up the ColdFusion config files?

Comment: Disabled firewall but same error occurred. However when I tried to telnet the port 1433 I got an error "Could not open connection to the host on port 1433. Connect failed". I am looking at this now.

Comment: SQL Server authentication is enabled. SQL Managment Studio connects to SQL Server.

Comment: When you say "and the default port is 1433", specifically where is set as the default?

Comment: I believe that SQL Server uses TCP port 1433 by default. I checked in SQL Server Configuration Manager, and the TCP port is 1433 (the dynamic ports are set to zero).

Comment: I think they changed that at some point and it defaulted to dynamic? IIRC, in some versions I had to explicitly set it to 1433 under TCP/IP > All ports. Not sure about 2012, so YMMV

Comment: [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39243343) to see what ports it is listening on `use master go xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Server is listening on'`

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but I have checked in SQL Configuration Manager, and SQL is listening (or trying to listen) on port 1433. I am going to do some checks with telnet again. Last night it appeared there may be a connection problem.

Comment: I disabled a couple of IPs in SQL Configuration Manager and the issues have been resolved. Not sure why those other IPs should have been an issue, but I thank responders for their comments.

Comment: Glad it is working! If you think it'll help someone else, feel free to add some details and write it up as an "answer".